# Windows Phone 8.1 - JSON (REST post/get/put) requests and their de/serialization

Tags: c#, json, rest, generics, windows-phone

I have multiple REST requests, where I want to get/post/put data in JSON format with different objects for each request.

However I do not want to repeat myself by writing call to the server and deserealization method for each request. However each request or response contains different object to de/serialize, how to write general method for calling and parsing it?

(note this is self-answered question, I want to share my help-request classes which are easy to use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using same method for different class types, you have to use Generic class. With that, you can set up custom de/serialization.

This is class for sending and receiving GET request :

```
public class JsonGet<O>
{
    public async Task<O> DoGetRequest(string url)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0]);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(
            url,
            "action",
            "get",
            DateTime.Now.Ticks
            ));

        var response = client.GetAsync(uri);

        HttpResponseMessage x = await response;
        if (x.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            //throw new ConnectionOutException("While posting: " + url + " we got the following status code: " + x.StatusCode);
        }
        HttpContent requestContent = x.Content;
        string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<O>(jsonContent);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<O>(jsonContent);
    }
}
```

Then you can easily get deserialized object by following. Note that the class you type into generic part (in this case it is class Defaults), is the type to be deserealized :

```
        JsonGet<Defaults> get = new JsonGet<Defaults>();
        Defaults myMethod = await get.DoGetRequest(Constants.Constants.UrlDefaults);
```

Very similarly, you can have class for PUT/POST requests

```
public class JsonSend<I, O>
    {

        public async Task<O> DoPostRequest(string url, I input)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0]);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(
                url,
                "action",
                "post",
                DateTime.Now.Ticks
                ));

            string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);

            StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(
                serialized,
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json");

            var response = client.PostAsync(uri, stringContent);

            HttpResponseMessage x = await response;
            if (x.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //throw new ConnectionOutException("While puting: " + url + " we got the following status code: " + x.StatusCode);
            }
            HttpContent requestContent = x.Content;
            string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<O>(jsonContent);
        }

        public async Task<O> DoPutRequest(string url, I input)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0]);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(
                url,
                "action",
                "put",
                DateTime.Now.Ticks
                ));

            var response = client.PutAsync(uri,
            new StringContent(
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input),
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage x = await response;
            if (x.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //throw new ConnectionOutException("While puting: " + url + " we got the following status code: " + x.StatusCode);
            }
            HttpContent requestContent = x.Content;
            string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<O>(jsonContent);
        }
    }
```

And then you can send and receive POST as following :

```
        JsonSend<User, UserReceived> register = new JsonSend<User, UserReceived>();
        UserReceived responseUser = await register.DoPostRequest(Constants.Constants.UrlRegister, user);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this generic menthod

```
  public static async Task<T> ExecuteGet<T, K>(string url, K obj) where T : class
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
            return default(T);
        var client = new HttpClient();
        string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        Debug.WriteLine("json Request :" + url + str);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url + str));

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var ResponceString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine("Json responce :" + ResponceString);
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(ResponceString);

            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(data, typeof(T));

        }
        else
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```